# Looking for a book from an old series about kids with magic sneakers that give them superpowers

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I checked this book out from a library in Indiana (U.S.A.) sometime in the early-to-mid 1980s. Written in English. A children's book; pretty short. Hardback. We're not talking a few hundred pages of text in a small font, as in a mass-market paperback, but we're not talking illustrations on every page with minimal text, as if it were meant to be read aloud to toddlers while they admired the pretty pictures, either. At a guess, the intended target audience *might* have been around 10 years old, with a margin of error of a few years either way.

Here is what I remember about the premise:

1. This book was a later installment in a series -- I can't remember what number, but definitely not the first installment.
2. I say this because, as the book begins, the main characters -- a group of schoolkids -- already have possession of nifty magic sneakers, having somehow acquired them in a previous adventure. I say "magic," but it's *conceivable* that there was some sort of "scientific" rationale which would technically make it science fiction instead of fantasy literature; I can't remember. The point is that wearing these sneakers gave the wearer some sort of superpower. (But only while they stayed on your feet, I believe.)
3. I *think* each pair of sneakers conferred a different power upon the wearer. I'm nearly sure that one pair gave its wearer the ability to run at super-speed, for instance. I'm not sure what the other powers were (although I'm thinking super-strength *might* have been one of them). As I recall, the sneakers were color-coded -- the red pair do one thing, the blue pair do another, and so forth.
4. I have this vague idea that the kids ended up running around in the middle of the night, using their powers to defeat some form of villainy. Nothing involving people dying; this book was slanted at too young an audience for that. Capturing a gang of burglars, perhaps.

I've never run across that book again. I've never read any other volumes in that series. I can't remember a thing about the title, nor the cover art, nor the author. (Except in the sense that I'm pretty sure the author was a new name to me at the time; not one of my established favorites because of work on a previous popular series.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The Adventures of the Sneeky Sneekers" series by  Mike Jaroch and F.A. Randy Jaroch. The books are: "[The Tornado](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19045012-the-tornado)", "The Ghost of Gleason Mansion" and "Washout at Liberty Valley"

> What would you do if some mysterious person gave you a gift with
> magical powers? Each of four brothers were given a gift of a pair of
> innocent looking sneakers, but the next thing anyone knows is one of
> the brothers is up in the top of a tree? What they discover about
> themselves and what they can do with their new-found powers takes them
> on an adventure of epic proportions! Not even Mother Nature's fury can
> stand up to the power of the Sneeky Sneekers!